# Let $P = (a, b, c)$ be a point in space. Which point of the xy-plane is nearest to $P$? Justify your answer.

Tags: calculus, vectors

Just confused on this question, would not the point in the $xy$ plane just be at $(a,b)$? and then the distance would be $c$.

So for example if $P = (1,2,3)$ would not the closest point on the $xy$ plane be $(1,2)$ with a distance of $3$?

Comment: Yes, but you still have to justify your answer.

Comment: the point in xy plane will also have 3 coordinates

Comment: One way to formally do this is to think of the points in the xy-plane as (x,y,0). Then find the x,y that minimizes the distance to (a,b,c).

Comment: $p_1 = (a,b,c)$, $p_2 = (x,y,0)$. The distance between $p_1,p_2$, denoted as $d(p_1,p_2)$ is given by

\begin{align}
d(p_1,p_2) &= \sqrt{(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 + (o-c)^2} \\ 
           &= \sqrt{(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 + c^2}
\end{align}

What do you think are the values of $x$ and $y$ that makes $d(p_1,p_2)$ the smallest possible?

Answer (score 1):

Using the distance formula, you want to minimize $$ (x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(0-c)^2$$

The minimum happens where $$x=a, y=b$$ which gives us the point $(a,b,0)$

That is the orthogonal projection of the point $(a,b,c)$ on the $xy$ plane.